# How to convert dollar sign to words in Python

Tags: python

I am looking to format something like "$100" to "100 dollars" using Python.

How can I do this?

I want to do some text processing from a news feed (RSS) using Python NLTK, but first I want to "clean up" that text a bit, so I thought about starting with the dollar signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this `if` statement:

```
s = "$100"
if '$' in s:
    print(s[1:] + ' dollar%s' % ('s' if int(s[1:]) != 1 else ''))
```

Output:

```
100 dollars
```

Also, for `"$1"` it would give `1 dollar` without `s` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Or use regex:

```
import re
s = '$100'
s1 = re.sub('\$([0-9]+)', '\g<1> dollars', s)
print(s1) # '100 dollars'
```

Maybe include decimals:

```
s = '$100.99'
s1 = re.sub('\$([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)', '\g<1> dollars', s)
print(s1) # 100.99 dollars
```

Comment: but what about 1 dollar,2 dollars ? have you seen 's'?

Comment: but it doesn't matter much i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use `if` AND `replace` method of string to get your desired result.

```
s = "$100"
if "$" in s:
    s = s.replace('$', "")
    s = s+" dollars"
    print(s)
```

Output:-

```
100 dollars
```

I hope it may help you

Answer (score -1):

```
a= $500
for i in a:
       if i==$:
            continue

       else:
            print(i,end='')
 print("Dollar")
```

output:
       500 dollar

Comment: `$500` should be a string